# Управление: числительное + слово "процент"

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные, управление

Как правильно говорить: *три и пять десятых процента/процентов, пять и пять десятых процента/проценто*в, *три с половиной процента/ов*, *пять с половиной процента/ов*? Какое слово в этих словосочетаниях главное?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **три и пять десятых процента, пять и пять десятых процента, три с половиной процента, пять с половиной процентов**.

Дробные числительные употребляются с существительными в форме единственного числа родительного падежа: двести девять целых и пять десятых тысячи, пять целых и пять десятых метра. То есть дробная часть управляет существительным.
А вот в случае с "половиной" управляет числительное: **три** с половиной **процента**, **пять** с половиной **процентов**.

См: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=285308